# Update base-files issue with freeze under AMD Ryzen 7

Tags: freeze, amd-processor

I have troubles with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS which run a small postgreSQL server.

It freezes very often.
As the server is under Ryzen 7 2700, I have tried many thing (cancel sleep mode, change consumption mode in grub, ...) but honestly nothing works and I have no idea where I have to check to find the solution.

In addition, this morning, after a new ramdom freeze, a `sudo apt update` + `sudo apt upgrade` stopped at blocked at base-file setting.

Could you help to stop freeze issue and have a "clean" ubuntu ?
I'm not a linux specialist but a "very enlightened" amateur

Comment: It might help if you clarify the actual problem; you mention it stopped at *base-file* settings (in your title you say *base-files*).  The package `base-files` is only a package of TEXT files that say what release you have installed (& other licensing type files); thus there is nothing *substantial* there, ie. https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/amd64/base-files/filelist shows what's included for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. If your machine has a problem with that; I'd check your disk & hardware for problems; or do you mean something else by *base-files* ?

Comment: First thx for help...

How I could check hardware issues ?
The only thing I have is the issue of base-files which block all upgrade process.

Comment: You should be specific in your question, ie. you mention Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but don't mention if this is a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server install, or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop install (you mention a Server app thus I assume server; but it's best to avoid us making assumptions!). It would be helpful if you copy/pasted what you actually see into your question (*or provided link to a picture we can view*); `base-files` is also a package which rarely changes (2-4 times per year for a LTS), but also often the last message you see is BEFORE the actual problem.. Can you SysRq command kernel on freeze?

Comment: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4.5/changelog shows the changelog & you can read the actual change.. ie. a Message of the Day TEXT file changed its message; hardly significant!!  If a server; I'd explore the machine logs for clues as to temperature or other problems (ie. I'm talking hardware logs here, not OS logs).. Also look on machine logs (systemd journal survives reboot). I'd do a memtest to confirm RAM is okay; cap-scan check PSU check etc... ie. generic hardware checks...

Answer (score 0):

After set -x just below the set -e command in /var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postins and restart an upgrade command the process blocked at `deb-systemd-invoke restart motd-news.timer`...

```
sudo apt install memtester
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  memtester
0 mis à jour, 1 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 8 non mis à jour.
2 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/17,6 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 54,3 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Paramétrage de base-files (12ubuntu4.5) ...
+ [ ! -e /etc/dpkg/origins/default ]
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ [ 12ubuntu4.4 =  ]
+ [ -d /usr/share/info ]
+ [ ! -f /usr/info/dir ]
+ [ ! -f /usr/share/info/dir ]
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ [ 12ubuntu4.4 !=  ]
+ rm -f /var/lib/update-notifier/release-upgrade-available
+ [ -x /usr/lib/update-manager/check-new-release ]
+ update_to_current_default profile /etc/profile
+ [ -f /etc/profile ]
+ md5sum /etc/profile
+ cut -f 1 -d
+ md5=9926b56bc6e576d4ad206dd82d38deff
+ grep -q 9926b56bc6e576d4ad206dd82d38deff /usr/share/base-files/profile.md5sums
+ cmp -s /usr/share/base-files/profile /etc/profile
+ update_to_current_default dot.profile /root/.profile
+ [ -f /root/.profile ]
+ md5sum /root/.profile
+ cut -f 1 -d
+ md5=d68ce7c7d7d2bb7d48aeb2f137b828e4
+ grep -q d68ce7c7d7d2bb7d48aeb2f137b828e4 /usr/share/base-files/dot.profile.md5sums
+ dpkg --compare-versions 12ubuntu4.4 lt-nl 7.7
+ motd_news_config=/etc/default/motd-news
+ [ 12ubuntu4.4 !=  ]
+ [ ! -e /etc/default/motd-news ]
+ dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile /etc/default/motd-news 11ubuntu11~ base-files -- configure 12ubuntu4.4
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ deb-systemd-helper unmask motd-news.timer
+ deb-systemd-helper --quiet was-enabled motd-news.timer
+ deb-systemd-helper enable motd-news.timer
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ [ -d /run/systemd/system ]
+ systemctl --system daemon-reload
+ [ -n 12ubuntu4.4 ]
+ _dh_action=restart
+ deb-systemd-invoke restart motd-news.timer
```

what is motd-news.timer ?

Edit from 22/01/2024 :
To allow system to do an upgrade, I have comment the line #162 (may be change) into the file /varlib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst where I found `deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'motd-news.timer' >/dev/null || true`.

With this comment, the process performed the `apt upgrade` or the `apt install something`. Since that → no freeze.

Note : I have performed an memtest and found ~49 errors on my 32 Go RAM.

Comment: To allow system to do an upgrade, I have comment the line #162 (may be change) into the file `/varlib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst` where I found `deb-systemd-invoke $_dh_action 'motd-news.timer' >/dev/null || true`.

With this comment, the process performed the apt upgrade or the apt install something.

Since that → no freeze.

Note : I have performed an memtest and found ~49 errors on my 32 Go RAM.

Comment: Please add this info from the above comment to the answer with an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500899/edit). After that, delete the comment.